# Google Docs toolbar zoomed out even when I press Cmd +

Tags: google-docs, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

Google Docs for one of my Chrome profiles is zoomed out. When I open a new page, both the toolbar and the document are quite zoomed out, and even when I press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or change the 100% dropdown menu and the document grows larger, the toolbar still stays tiny. I haven't found any solutions to this. I tried checking Chrome settings but couldn't find anything relevant.

[image: screenshot - zoomed in to 150%—notice toolbar is still small]
[image: screenshot - default zoomed out]